# How to check if I can go back / use pop on react-native-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

So, there is a screen that I'm using a javascript navbar instead of the react-native-navigation one (because of [this bug](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/1971#issuecomment-353198804)).

I need to show a back button only if it can go back (if it's not the first screen in the stack).

Any way to check if it can go back?
Something like `navigator.canBoBack()` or `navigator.getCurrentScreenStack().lenght > 1`.

Comment: @Siggy thanks but my issue is specific to the `react-native-navigation` library for `react-native`, not the browser. I've added it to the title to be more clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if the screen's `commandType` prop is either `Push` or `ShowModal` and call set buttons accordingly.

```
const canGoBack =
      this.props.commandType === 'Push' ||
      this.props.commandType === 'ShowModal'
```

Comment: Thanks! That does solve the question. I edited to add a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You may track if your able to go back like this :

```
const prevGetStateForAction = Navigator.router.getStateForAction;

Navigator.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
  // Do not allow to go back from Login
  if (action.type === "Navigation/BACK" && state && state.routes[state.index].routeName === "Login") {
    return null;
  }
  // Do not allow to go back to Login
  if (action.type === "Navigation/BACK" && state) {
    const newRoutes = state.routes.filter(r => r.routeName !== "Login");
    const newIndex = newRoutes.length - 1;
    return prevGetStateForAction(action, { index: newIndex, routes: newRoutes });
  }
  return prevGetStateForAction(action, state);
};
```

See this :
https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/295

Comment: Thanks but I don't use react-navigation, I use react-native-navigation https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation